# High CPU usage for DJango 1.4 on Windows 2012

Tags: performance, python-2.7, 32-bit, windows-server-2012

We migrated to Helicon Zoo on Windows 2012 (from ISAPI on 2008). Problem is that the users started complaining about random slowdowns and timeouts with the application.

The Python is 2.7 32-bit (due to Zoo requirements).
That said, the problem is not Zoo related, as the runserver seems to exhibit same issues.

The CPU shows to be the highest usage, practically reaching 80%-90% on every request.
On Linux, same application works just fine.

Are there any known caveats with Python 2.7 32-bit on Windows 2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in 32-bit version of Python shipped with Zoo.

Installing a 64-bit version and modifying the Zoo engine to use it, has boosted things significantly.